# JSON Writes for Java List

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am working on an backend server in Play Framework in Scala. However, I am calling an external library (written in java) that returns a Java list (util.List). I created a writes for the object that is contained in the List, however I don't know how to write the writes for the actual List so that it can be generic (no need to write a "writes" for both List and List, just the writes for A and B).

I know I could use JavaConversions to convert the Java list to a Scala Seq (that already has Writes implemented), but since speed is essential, I would like to not do the extra conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsArray, JsValue, Json, Writes}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

implicit def jListWrites[A: Writes] = new Writes[java.util.List[A]] {
  override def writes(o: util.List[A]): JsValue = {
    JsArray(o.asScala.map(Json.toJson(_)))
  }
}
```

You don't create a single `Writes` but rather a method that can create them for any type that has `Writes` defined.

You said you want to avoid `JavaConversions`, but as you can see it is difficult as `JsArray` expects a `Seq[JsValue]` anyway so you need to construct a scala `Seq` one way or another.

What I shown here is more or less equivalent to converting java `List` to scala `mutable.Buffer` using `asScala` and using default `Writes` for `Traversable`.

Note that conversions are probably not as expansive as you think, they just create a wrapper, no copying involved.

Here is the best what I could come with in terms of performance

```
implicit def jListWrites[A: Writes] = new Writes[java.util.List[A]] {
  override def writes(o: util.List[A]): JsValue = {
    val buffer = new Array[JsValue](o.size)
    var i = 0
    while (i < o.size) {
      buffer(i) = Json.toJson(o.get(i))
      i += 1
    }

    JsArray(buffer)
  }
}
```

It takes 29 ms for 1000000 `Int`s compared to 39 ms for the straightforward implementation. Note that `Int` is easy to convert, if your objects are more complex the speedup will be smaller.

Converting 20000 of those `case class C(num: Int, n2: Int, s: String)` gives equal results (straightforward is even faster by 0.14 ms).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can code a `Writes` that reuses the existing one for Scala `List`

```
import java.util.{ List => JList }
implicit def JListWrites[T](implicit sw: Writes[List[T]]): Writes[JList[T]]) = Write[JList[T]] { jlist => 
  sw.writes(jlist.asScala) 
}
```